# I want to get a method by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to get a method by reflection,but the method has multiple overloads..and the method's parameters is a generic type..How can I do?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test obj = new test();
        Type[] types = { typeof(string) };
        var method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Say", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, types, null);
        method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "hello world" });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class test
{
    private void Say(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    private void Say<T>(T t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

I can get `private void Say(string value)`..but I want to get `private void Say<T>(T t)`..

`Type[] types = { typeof(string) };` Here how to set up here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke generics overloaded method using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623538/invoke-generics-overloaded-method-using-reflection)

Comment: [MethodInfo.IsGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.isgenericmethod(v=vs.85).aspx) is all you need.

Comment: Then use the [MakeGenericMethod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) operation of your MethodInfo and you got it!

Comment: Interesting question, but what are you trying to achieve here? What is your use case that means you have to access a private method through reflection and can it not be better achieved without doing so?

Comment: In fact, test in an assembly. Call test place again in another assembly. I do not want another assembly can access directly to it. . So I put the test is declared as internal. . After the transfer test program focused on the use of reflection to create it, and call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are you ways.

**Get all methods and find that one you're looking for**

```
obj.GetType().GetMethods().Single(m=>m.GetParameters().Length = /* parameter count*/ && /* next condition */);
```

**Use Expression tree**
In my opinion is nicer and less error prone but can be used only when you known which method you want in compile time.

You need some helper method that extract Method for expression tree.

```
public static MethodInfo Method(Expression<Action> methodAccess)
{
  return ((MethodCallExpression)methodAccess.Body).Method;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Get(()=>obj.Say<string>("My param")).GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

Compiler will take care of selecting method and helper method will extract MethodInfo from expression tree. GetGenericMethodDefinition() call will give you open-generic version of selected method.

Comment: but 'say' method is private..I must be using reflection to get this method then invoke..

Comment: So..I want to according parameters type and parameters count to get method..but I don't know how to look for it...

Comment: I've updated answer with sample how to find method based on parameter count

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I would rather go for a solution like:

```
public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(object obj, string methodName, Type genericParameter)
{
    var method = obj.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.Equals(methodName) && m.IsGenericMethod);
    return method.MakeGenericMethod(genericParameter);
}
```

And then call it with something like:

```
GetGenericMethod(obj, "Say", typeof(string));
```

You will then be able to invoke it like any other methods.

Comment: thanks for your answer..but maybe method name the same and 'IsGenericMethod' has many in class test

Comment: You can probably play with the number of parameters... But yeah it is not as precise as Novakov solution.